# How to prevent automatic onmouseover after onfocus?

Tags: javascript, html, css, onmouseover, onfocus

I have created an HTML table with three links in each of the rows. My goal is to highlight a row whenever the user (1) hovers over it or (2) enters a link by pressing <kbd>tab</kbd>. I would also like to make sure that only one row is highlighted at a time. Here is a simplified version of my HTML (**show.htm**):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="show.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="show.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
  <h2>Basic Information:</h2>
  <table>
    <tr class="data">
      <td>London:</td>
      <td><a href="http://example.com/london_001.htm">Part 1</a></td>
      <td><a href="http://example.com/london_002.htm">Part 2</a></td>
      <td><a href="http://example.com/london_003.htm">Part 3</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="data">
      <td>New York:</td>
      <td><a href="http://example.com/newyork_001.htm">Part 1</a></td>
      <td><a href="http://example.com/newyork_002.htm">Part 2</a></td>
      <td><a href="http://example.com/newyork_003.htm">Part 3</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="data">
      <td>Tokyo:</td>
      <td><a href="http://example.com/tokyo_001.htm">Part 1</a></td>
      <td><a href="http://example.com/tokyo_002.htm">Part 2</a></td>
      <td><a href="http://example.com/tokyo_003.htm">Part 3</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="data">
      <td>Rio de Janeiro:</td>
      <td><a href="http://example.com/riodejaneiro_001.htm">Part 1</a></td>
      <td><a href="http://example.com/riodejaneiro_002.htm">Part 2</a></td>
      <td><a href="http://example.com/riodejaneiro_003.htm">Part 3</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="data">
      <td>Melbourne:</td>
      <td><a href="http://example.com/melbourne_001.htm">Part 1</a></td>
      <td><a href="http://example.com/melbourne_002.htm">Part 2</a></td>
      <td><a href="http://example.com/melbourne_003.htm">Part 3</a></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the Javascript (**show.js**):

```
window.onload = function(){
  var rows = document.getElementsByClassName('data');
  var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
  var len = rows.length;
  var old_index = -1;
  var set_color = function(index, color){
    return function(){
      if(index !== old_index){
        if(old_index !== -1){
          rows[old_index].style.backgroundColor = null;
        }
        rows[index].style.backgroundColor = color;
        old_index = index;
      }
    }
  }
  var i, j;
  for(i = 0; i < len; i++){
    rows[i].onmouseover = set_color(i, '#FFFFBB');
    rows[i].onmouseout = set_color(i, null);
    for(j = 0; j < 3; j++){
      links[i*3+j].onfocus = set_color(i, '#FFFFBB');
      links[i*3+j].onblur = set_color(i, null);
    }
  }
}
```

And, finally, here is the CSS (**show.css**):

```
table{
  margin:auto;
  width:98%;
  border-collapse:collapse;
  border:none;
}
td{
  border-top:1px solid gray;
  border-bottom:1px solid gray;
  border-left:none;
  border-right:none;
  vertical-align:center;
  font-weight:bold;
}
.data{
  background-color:rgba(120, 120, 240, 0.4);
  font-family:Tahoma;
  font-size:16px;
}
.data>td{
    padding:6px 16px;
}
```

Whenever the page is loaded and I press <kbd>tab</kbd>, the first link receives focus but the row on which the mouse pointer rests (not necessarily the first row) gets highlighted. It seems that the `onmouseover` event fires immediately after the `onfocus`, even though no mouse movement is actually made. How to tackle this issue (without using any external library like JQuery)? Any help will be appreciated.

---

**Update:**

I have modified my Javascript code in order to detect actual mouse movement (borrowing the idea from Nick Bull’s answer). But the problem has remained. I need further help.

```
window.onload = function(){
  var rows = document.getElementsByClassName('data');
  var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
  var len = rows.length;
  var old_index = -1;
  var old_coords = {X:event.screenX, Y:event.screenY};
  var set_color = function(index, color, keyboard_event){
    return function(){
      if(keyboard_event || event.screenX !== old_coords.X || event.screenY !== old_coords.Y){
        if(index !== old_index){
          if(old_index !== -1){
            rows[old_index].style.backgroundColor = null;
          }
          rows[index].style.backgroundColor = color;
          old_index = index;
          if(!keyboard_event){
            old_coords.X = event.screenX;
            old_coords.Y = event.screenY;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  var i, j;
  for(i = 0; i < len; i++){
    rows[i].onmouseover = set_color(i, '#FFFFBB', false);
    rows[i].onmouseout = set_color(i, null, false);
    for(j = 0; j < 3; j++){
      links[i*3+j].onfocus = set_color(i, '#FFFFBB', true);
      links[i*3+j].onblur = set_color(i, null, true);
    }
  }
}
```

---

The document loads:

[image: screenshot]

The first <kbd>tab</kbd> is pressed:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I ultimately killed the demon (ugly enough, but works nonetheless):
(1) I created two different variables for the last hovered index and the last focused index
(2) I created four different functions for `onmouseover`, `onmouseout`, `onfocus` and `onblur`
(3) I added a timeout to ensure that `onmouseover` does not fire immediately after `onfocus`.

Here is the modified Javascript code:

```
window.onload = function(){
  var rows = document.getElementsByClassName('data');
  var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
  var len = rows.length;
  var color = '#FFFFBB';
  var hovered_index = -1;
  var focused_index = -1;
  var mouseover_allowed = true;
  var set_color_onmouseover = function(index){
    return function(){
      if(mouseover_allowed){
        if(focused_index !== -1){
          rows[focused_index].style.backgroundColor = null;
        }
        rows[index].style.backgroundColor = color;
        hovered_index = index;
      }
    }
  }
  var set_color_onmouseout = function(index){
    return function(){
      if(hovered_index !== -1){
        rows[index].style.backgroundColor = null;
        hovered_index = -1;
      }
    }
  }
  var set_color_onfocus = function(index){
    return function(){
      if(hovered_index !== -1){
        rows[hovered_index].style.backgroundColor = null;
      }
      rows[index].style.backgroundColor = color;
      focused_index = index;
      // disable onmouseover for the next 100 milliseconds
      mouseover_allowed = false;
      setTimeout(function(){ mouseover_allowed = true; }, 100);
    }
  }
  var set_color_onblur = function(index){
    return function(){
      if(focused_index !== -1){
        rows[index].style.backgroundColor = null;
        focused_index = -1;
      }
    }
  }
  var i, j;
  for(i = 0; i < len; i++){
    rows[i].onmouseover = set_color_onmouseover(i);
    rows[i].onmouseout = set_color_onmouseout(i);
    for(j = 0; j < 3; j++){
      links[i*3+j].onfocus = set_color_onfocus(i);
      links[i*3+j].onblur = set_color_onblur(i);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Test if the mouse has truly moved in your `onmouseover` event?

So:

```
rows[i].onmouseover = set_color(i, '#FFFFBB');
```

becomes

```
var lastEventCoords = {};

document.getElementById("id").addEventListener("mouseover", function( event ) {   
  // If coords match, go home
  if (lastEventCoords.X == event.screenX && 
      lastEventCoords.Y == event.screenY) {
    return;
  }
  // If they don't match (i.e., mouse actually moved), this function will run
  else {
    alert('#FFFFBB')
  }

  lastEventCoords = { X: event.screenX, Y: event.screenY };
}, false);
```

**EDIT**: Working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xsec74zt/).

**EDIT**: For the updated question, still editing so hold on:

First an event for the key press for a tab:

```
function checkTabPress(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 9) {
    var rows = document.getElementsByClassName("data");

    if (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      rows[i].style.backgroundColor = null;
    }

    document.getActiveElement().style.backgroundColor = "#123456";
  }
}

document.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
  checkTabPress(e);
}, false);
```

Comment: If I do this, `onmouseover` is not having its desired effect, i.e. changing the background color of the hovered row.

Comment: Why not? It will, if the last `onmouseover` event's coordinates aren't identical to the former `ommouseover` event.

Comment: @SharanyaDutta Added a comment to the JS to help you see where that decision occurs.

Comment: Yes, I can understand your code. But somehow it is not working. I even added `alert('Mouse moved!');` within the `else` block. But no alert box popped up during an actual mouse movement.

Comment: @SharanyaDutta Sure, no offense meant, a lot of people wouldn't understand! Very strange... Let me have a think.

Comment: By the way, the first parameter of `addEventListener` should be `mouseover` rather than `onmouseover`.

Comment: @SharanyaDutta You are right, I need to stop answering questions on my phone before checking my code. There was also an issue with `lastEventCoords` being set to in the last line (originally it read `lastCoords = ...`, make sure that's changed too. Massive apologies, here the working code: https://jsfiddle.net/xsec74zt/

Comment: Certainly you don’t need to apologize. Thank you for your efforts. Please see the update and, if possible, provide me with further help.

Comment: Upvoted for your sincere efforts, though unfortunately that was little help to me. See my answer.